# How to calculate a range of cells on editing the rage in the Google Spreadsheets using Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I am trying to do is, whenever any cell in the range (B1:B10) is edited I want to sum up the values within the range (B1:B10) and add this to cell B11. I used the following code but it adds the formula into the cell. I want to put only the summed value, not the formula itself.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var cell = e.range;

  if(cell.getA1Notation() === "B1:B10" && ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "TEST"){
    ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B11").setFormula("=SUM(B1:B10)");
  }    

}
```

I tried to find an answer on Google, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: First the script should have to read the range values. This could be done using `SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues()`.

Second, the script should sum the values. This should be done using JavaScript.

Third, the script shoud write the sum to the corresponding cell. This could be done by using `SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues(sum)`. If you need further help, please show what you have tried to read the values, make the sum and write the result. If you have no idea about where to start, start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Comment: Because I do not have any idea (also I couldn't find a tutorial online) how to calculate the values in a range of cells. I used `.setFormula("=SUM(B1:B10)")` this method to get the sum and set that to 'B11' using `.getRange("B11")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.filter()` and `Array.reduce()`, like this:

```js
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet;
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 2
    || e.range.rowStart > 10
    || (sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName() !== 'TEST') {
    return;
  }
  const rangeToWatch = sheet.getRange('B1:B10');
  const targetCell = sheet.getRange('B11');
  const total = rangeToWatch.getValues()
    .flat()
    .filter(value => typeof value === 'number')
    .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current, 0);
  targetCell.setValue(total);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just get rid of the code and "hide" the formula in another cell. Let's say you need to have in A11 the text "TOTAL", then you can delete first what is in B11 and then put in A11:

={"TOTAL",SUM(B1:B10)}

This way it will expand unto B11 but if you click on that cell you'll only see the value, not the formula

PS: if you try this disable or delete the code